# Applying function to a view after getting results of views query

Tags: mysql, relational-database, stored-functions

I have a table called results that has the following structure:

```
---------------------------------
| id_test | id_student | result |
---------------------------------
```

Where `id_test (INT)`, `id_student(INT)`, `result (INT between 0 and 100 (inclusive))`.

**Task** is to create a view, based on the table, and calculate statistics on the result column (having a cut-off value of 50) and add them in another column to the view.

I have created a stored function that performs calculation of a certain statistics for the result:

```
FUNCTION `calc_stat`(student INT, test INT, res INT) RETURNS float
BEGIN
    declare tests INT;
    declare totaltestamount INT unsigned DEFAULT 35;
    declare weighted_res FLOAT;
    declare maxres INT;

select max(result) into maxres 
from results
where results.id_student = student;

select count(*) into tests 
from results
where results.id_test = test;

set weighted_res = res/maxres*tests/totaltestamount;

return weighted_res;
END
```

As well as the view:

```
create view `statistics` as
    select `id_test` AS `id_test`, `id_student` AS `id_student`, `result` AS `result`,calc_stat(`id_student`, `id_test`,`result`) AS `statistics`
    from `results`
```

The only part, which I don't get is the cut-off value, since I am not sure, how to retrieve the table with results>50 and only then apply the function based on the retrieved view. Is there any way to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

If you  want to show only the rows with result > 50 , only add this in view :

```
create view `statistics` as
select `id_test` AS `id_test`, `id_student` AS `id_student`, `result` AS `result`,calc_stat(`id_student`, `id_test`,`result`) AS `statistics`
from `results` WHERE `result` > 50
```

If you  want to show all rows and only apply the function on records with result > 50 . Add condition to the function. Something like this.

```
FUNCTION `calc_stat`(student INT, test INT, res INT) RETURNS float
BEGIN
declare tests INT;
declare totaltestamount INT unsigned DEFAULT 35;
declare weighted_res FLOAT;
declare maxres INT;

select max(result) into maxres 
from results
where results.id_student = student;

select count(*) into tests 
from results
where results.id_test = test;

set weighted_res = res/maxres*tests/totaltestamount;

if res < 50 then 
  set weighted_res = 0 //  or something 
end if

return weighted_res;
END
```

Comment: if res < 50 then 
  set weighted_res = 0 //  or something 
end if

Comment: that's something clear. And I know that, but what I want is to retrieve the results with >50 and then apply the function on the retrieved results, considering that that's the whole table(not half of it).

Comment: What you want to show in column "statistics" on view , if the result is < 50 ?

Comment: So, first I want to get all of the entries which are having result less than 50 and considering retrieved result as whole dataset, compute statistics. Basically I have achieved that adding condition into select clauses inside the stored function.